# Multiple events after update in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to notify users through sms whenever a row gets updated. I've added the following code -

```
$transaction->commit();
$mobiletemp = User::find()->leftJoin('auth_assignment', 'auth_assignment.user_id = user.id')->select('mobileno')->andWhere(['auth_assignment.item_name' => 'c_apo'])->column();
$mobile = implode(",", $mobiletemp);
return $this->redirect('http://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?' . http_build_query(['sender'=>'TSTMSG', 'route'=>'4', 'mobiles'=> $mobile, 'authkey'=>'My Auth Key', 'country'=>'0','message'=>('Dear Sir, WP '. $wpno. ' is waiting for your approval. Please take necessary steps. Thank You.')]));
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->wp_no]);
```

With this code user is getting sms notification. But, the there's a return code from the service provider which is being displayed as output. And the last piece of code to redirect to the view page is not getting read. I have to add multiple block of this notification code after update. Please let me know what is the best possible to way to handle this situation. I want to display the view after update also, users should get the notifications.

My present code after using curl

```
if ($flag) {
    $transaction->commit();
    $mobiletemp = User::find()->leftJoin('auth_assignment', 'auth_assignment.user_id = user.id')->select('mobileno')->andWhere(['auth_assignment.item_name' => 'c_apo'])->column();
    $mobile = implode(",", $mobiletemp);
    $curl = new curl\Curl();
    $response = $curl->setGetParams(['sender'=>'TSTMSG', 'route'=>'4', 'mobiles'=> $mobile, 'authkey'=>'My Auth Code', 'country'=>'0','message'=>('Dear Sir, WP '. $wpno. ' is waiting for your approval. Please take necessary steps. Thank You.')])->get('http://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php');
    if ($curl->errorCode === null) {
         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->wp_no]);
    }else {
         // List of curl error codes here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
        switch ($curl->errorCode) {

            case 6:
                //host unknown example
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "linslin/yii2-curl": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: why dont you use `curl` to send request to the api rather than using `return redirect` the next line will never be executed, you can use [**`THIS`**](https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl) library for curl calls.

Comment: Giving it a try...

Comment: see the answer below

Comment: that is odd, i just ran your code and received this response `386545766e4a393934313430` from the api against the dummy mobile number, can you remove the extension and run `composer update` and then use `composer require --prefer-dist linslin/yii2-curl "*"` to install it again.

Comment: also are you able to run the sample request i added below on top of my answer , or it gives the same error there too.?

Comment: There also I get the same error. Also, I used the above command to install curl.

Comment: strange **⊙﹏⊙** what version does `compose show -i` show for the `linslin/yii2-curl` and does the file `vendor\linslin\yii2-curl\Curl.php` exists ? and if does it should have the `setGetParams` function on line `243`

Comment: Version 1.0.3. I don't see setGenParams function in Curl.php

Comment: you are not using the latest version of `Yii2 V2.0.15.1`? it should be `V 1.2.1` for `linslin/curl` you can see the latest file here https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl/blob/master/Curl.php#L243

Comment: also what are your `minumum-stability` and `prefer-stable` values in `composer.json`

Comment: "minimum-stability": "stable",.... I ran composer update few mins ago that updated my yii2 version to 2.0.15.1... but the curl version is 1.0.3

Comment: can you share you `composer.json` into your question.

Comment: I've added composer.json in the question.

Comment: hmmm, when installing does it says `loading from the cache` or `downloading` like this https://imgur.com/a/euoZ4Go ? try `composer clearcache` and install again ijust used fresh install and used your `composer.json` and it installed the latest version

Comment: The yii2-curl version is solved now. I've updated to 1.2.1.

Comment: what was the reason can you add it to your question so that it might help others who get into the same issue

Comment: I had to install php curl and then update to latest version of yii2-curl

Comment: Aah! i didnt realized that it could be the reason, good catch, i will add this into the answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `curl` to send the request to the API and then use

`return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->wp_no]);`

For the Curl calls you can use [**`linslin`**](https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl) library for Yii2 which is very easy to use.

> Just make sure you have cURL installed or take the following steps to
>   install cURL.
>
> - First Install CURL by typing `$ sudo apt-get install curl`
> - Then Restart Apache by typing `$ sudo service apache2 restart`
> - Then Install PHP5 CURL by typing `$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl`
> - Will prompt to install... type `y` or `yes`!
> - Then Restart Apache by typing `$ sudo service apache2 restart` Done!

A simple curl `get` request using `linslin/Curl` will look like this.

```
// GET request with GET params
// http://example.com/?key=value&scondKey=secondValue
$curl = new curl\Curl();
$response = $curl->setGetParams([
        'key' => 'value',
        'secondKey' => 'secondValue'
     ])
     ->get('http://example.com/');
```

So your code will look like this

```
$transaction->commit();
$mobiletemp = User::find()->leftJoin('auth_assignment', 'auth_assignment.user_id = user.id')->select('mobileno')->andWhere(['auth_assignment.item_name' => 'c_apo'])->column();
$mobile = implode(",", $mobiletemp);
$curl = new curl\Curl();
$response = $curl->setGetParams(['sender'=>'TSTMSG', 'route'=>'4', 'mobiles'=> $mobile, 'authkey'=>'My Auth Key', 'country'=>'0','message'=>('Dear Sir, WP '. $wpno. ' is waiting for your approval. Please take necessary steps. Thank You.')])
         ->get('http://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php');

if ($curl->errorCode === null) {
     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->wp_no]);
} else {
     // List of curl error codes here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
    switch ($curl->errorCode) {

        case 6:
            //host unknown example
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error - Call to undefined method linslin\yii2\curl\Curl::setGetParams()

Comment: did you installed the extension ? @Tanmay

Comment: that is really strange can you you update your question with the exact code you are using after the update? @Tanmay